# Pandas create boolean column from subset index array

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I would like to create a boolean column in a pandas data frame of length 499.
I have an array a of index values :

```
a = np.array([206, 252, 272, 315, 349, 374, 394, 406, 440, 466])
```

I would like a column of  True values at these index positions in the df data frame.
Simplified example to work on:

```
arr = np.array(range(0,499))
df = pd.DataFrame(data = arr, columns = ['var1'])
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of 499 `False` values and use `.loc` to set `True` to selected rows from `a` array:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[False]*499, columns=['var1'])
df.iloc[a] = True
```

Output:

```
>>> df[df['var1'] == True]
     var1
206  True
252  True
272  True
315  True
349  True
374  True
394  True
406  True
440  True
466  True
```